# Get-Member not showing all properties of ADUser

Tags: powershell

I want to find out all available properties of ADUser.
Runnig this command

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Get-Member -MemberType properties | Where-Object {$_.name -eq 'ipPhone'}`

retruns nothing. Looks like ADuser doesn't have an 'ipPhone' property but it does. Running

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | select ipPhone
```

proves that.
Why get-member doesn't reveal all properties of ADuser?

Thanks

Comment: `Get-Member` only outputs properties for the first user returned by `Get-ADUser`. Try `Get-ADUser -Filter 'ipPhone -like "*"' -Properties * |Select-Object -First 1 |Get-Member -MemberType properties -Name ipPhone` instead

Comment: You are a legend! Works great, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're observing is due to an unfortunate combination of behaviors of the `ActiveDirectory` cmdlets and `Get-Member`.

The `Get-AD*` cmdlets all return "elastic" output objects - they have dynamic properties that only populate if the underlying directory entry has a value in the corresponding Active Directory attribute. As a result, not all properties (like `ipPhone`, which might be empty/unset for some users, for example) will be populated for each output object.

`Get-Member` works by inspecting the *type* of each object that you pipe to it, and only analyze the same type of object once, suppressing any further analysis/output for subsequent objects of the same type.

When you combine these two behaviors, you risk having `Get-ADUser` output multiple objects that has a specific property (eg. `ipPhone`) populated, but `Get-Member` will never pick up on it if the *first* `ADUser` object it sees does *not* have a value for `ipPhone`.

To work around this, make sure you only pipe objects/users to `Get-Member` that are certain to have a value in `ipPhone`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'ipPhone -like "*"' -Properties * |Select-Object -First 1 |Get-Member -MemberType properties -Name ipPhone
```

---

If you need to generate a complete list of properties (say, for `Select-Object` before exporting the data to CSV, for example), enumerate all the objects and collect the property names individually:

```
# Fetch all (relevant) objects
$allUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $true } -Properties

# enumerate all possible property names, remove duplicates
$allPropertyNames = $allUsers |ForEach-Object PropertyNames |Sort-Object -Unique

# now we can properly select any possible property
$allUsers |Select $allPropertyNames |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You're amazing! Your last piece of code is exactly what i'm looking for! I need a general way to inspect every possible property of an object. Armed with your code I can dig more into the AD modules! Much appreciate!

Comment: @bigapple99 That's great to hear, you're welcome! If this solves your problem, consider marking my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark outline on the left :-)